# Referenced column is not working correct with @ManyToOne hibernate-mapping

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem with my mapping OneToMany. My exception is 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.lcdut.model.SubjectsModel column: groups (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

If I use udpatetable or insert false, it's the same problem((

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subjects")
public class SubjectsModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "groups")
    private int groups;
    ...........
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "groups", referencedColumnName = "id_group")
    })
    private StudentsModel studentsModel;
    ........
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class StudentsModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "pib")
    private String pib;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_group")
    ........
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentsModel")
    private Set<SubjectsModel> subjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "groups")
private int groups;
...........
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "groups", referencedColumnName = "id_group")
})
private StudentsModel studentsModel;
........
```

These two fields are mapped by same column. You don't need `private int groups;`. Remove it and everything will work.

Comment: When I do it, I have another error((                                                                           Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property groups found for type SubjectsModel!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the right way, it should be an 1:n-relation and it should work like the following (column/foreign key studentsid must exist as int in the database):

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "subjects")
    public class SubjectsModel {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "studentsid")
        private StudentsModel studentsModel;
        ........
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "students")
    public class StudentsModel {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "pib")
        private String pib;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentsModel")
        private Set<SubjectsModel> subjects;
    }
```